# Young's inequality for convolutions

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution

Let's assume that the convolution $f * g$ is continuous with $\lim_{|x| \to \infty}(f*g)(x) = 0$ and that $f, g \in L^2$. Then the following inequality holds

$$ \| f * g \|_{\infty} \leq \| f \|_2 \|g\|_2.$$

Can someone give me a hint in order to prove this? The left side can be written as

$$ \| f * g \|_{\infty} = \max_{x \in \mathbb R} \left| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-u)g(u) \operatorname{d} u\right|$$

But know I'm stuck.. I think the Cauchy Schwarz inequality could be used here because what's inside the absolute value looks similar to the inner product.

Comment: Right. For a fixed $x$, consider the function $F(u) = f(x-u)$. What do you know about $F$?

Comment: If you have it available, I tend to think the most natural way to approach this would be with $H\ddot{o}lder's$inequality.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then, $F$ is also square integrable, so $F \in L^2$.

Comment: So far so good. What else?

Comment: @DanielFischer $F$ is a shifted version of $f$.. But I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Shifted and reflected. What does that say about the relation between $\lVert F\rVert_2$ and $\lVert f\rVert_2$?

Comment: @DanielFischer that $|\ F\|_2 = \|f\|_2$, since square integrating a function or the shifted and reflected version of $f$ over the real line has the same value. If this is true I might have the idea

Comment: Yes, $\lVert F\rVert_2 = \lVert f\rVert_2$. So, what might your idea be?

Comment: @DanielFischer If $F(u) = \max_{x \in \mathbb R} f(x-u)$ we have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(u)g(u) du$ which is the scalar product of $L_2$ for the case that $g(u)$ is real. In this case, cauchy inequality can be applied which proves the claim.

Comment: $F(u) = \max_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f(x-u)$ doesn't make (much) sense, that is a constant not depending on $u$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hm okay. Can Cauchy-Schwartz be applied here at all?  $\|f\|_2 \|g\|_2 = \|F\|_2 \|g\|_2 \geq |(F,g)| = |\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(u)\overline{g(u)} \operatorname{d} u| = ...$ - I don't see how to get the max in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $1 \leqslant p \leqslant +\infty$. For $x\in \mathbb{R}$ [it works with the same argument in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $n > 0$], let $\tau_x \colon L^p(\mathbb{R}) \to L^p(\mathbb{R})$ be given by

$$\tau_x(f) \colon u \mapsto f(u-x).$$

By the translation-invariance of the Lebesgue measure, $\tau_x$ is an isometry of $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for every $x$.

Further, let $\rho \colon L^p(\mathbb{R}) \to L^p(\mathbb{R})$ be the reflection, $\rho(f) \colon u \mapsto f(-u)$. Then $\rho$ is also an isometry of $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ since the Lebesgue measure is also invariant under reflection.

Thus for any $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ we can write

$$(f\ast g)(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x-u)g(u)\,du = \int_\mathbb{R} \bigl(\rho(\tau_x(f))\bigr)(u)g(u)\,du.$$

For real-valued functions, we then see

$$(f\ast g)(x) = \langle \rho(\tau_x(f)), g\rangle_{L^2},\tag{1}$$

and for complex-valued functions, we need to conjugate one of the arguments of the inner product, and then note that complex conjugation is also an isometry of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $1\leqslant p \leqslant +\infty$.

Now we can apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to the right hand side of $(1)$ to obtain

$$\lvert (f\ast g)(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert \rho(\tau_x(f))\rVert_2\cdot \lVert g\rVert_2\tag{2}.$$

But since $\rho$ and $\tau_x$ are isometries, the right hand side of $(2)$ is independent of $x$, and we have

$$\lvert (f\ast g)(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_2\cdot\lVert g\rVert_2.\tag{3}$$

By $(3)$, the convolution $f\ast g$ is uniformly bounded, and taking the supremum over all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ yields

$$\lVert f\ast g\rVert_\infty = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \lvert (f\ast g)(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_2\cdot\lVert g\rVert_2.\tag{4}$$

Since $f\ast g$ is continuous and $(f\ast g)(x) \to 0$ for $\lvert x\rvert \to \infty$ - note that these properties need not be assumed, they can be proved under the assumptions - the supremum in $(4)$ is actually attained, and can be replaced by $\max$ if one so wishes.

---

Basically the same argument, using the more general Hölder inequality instead of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality shows that for $1\leqslant p,q\leqslant +\infty$ with $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$ we have

$$\lVert f\ast g\rVert_\infty \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_p\cdot \lVert g\rVert_q$$

for all $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $g\in L^q(\mathbb{R})$.

For $1\leqslant p < +\infty$, the continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, and from that follows that for any fixed $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ the function $x \mapsto \tau_x(f)$ is continuous, which shows that $f\ast g$ is continuous - if $p = \infty$, then $q = 1 < \infty$, and we note that we have

$$(f\ast g)(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(u)g(x-u)\,du,$$

so the continuity of $x\mapsto \tau_x(g)$ yields the continuity of $f\ast g$.

For $1 < p,q < +\infty$, we have

$$\lim_{\lvert x\rvert\to\infty} (f\ast g)(x) = 0,$$

as one can again see by using the denseness of $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^q(\mathbb{R})$ then, but that need not hold in the $\{ p,q\} = \{1,\infty\}$ case.