# Proof of young's inequality for convolution

Tags: fourier-analysis

Suppose $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n), g \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I would like to show that $|| f*g||_{L^{\infty}} \leq ||f||_{L^p}||g||_{L^q}$ for $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1.$

my main idea was to use Holder's inequality. This means that I have

$||fg||_{L^1} \leq ||f||_{L^p} ||g||_{L^q}$
Now I need to show $||f*g||_{L^\infty} \leq || fg||_{L^1}$

Is this the case? Why is this true?

Comment: No, it is not true: It's trivial to come up with examples of functions $f$ and $g$ such that $\|fg\|_1 = 0$ but the convolution is non-zero.

Comment: Could ypu give me a hint on how to solve the problem then?

Comment: Daniel Fischer's answer to [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046817/youngs-inequality-for-convolutions) gives details for the case $p=q=2$ and then sketches the necessary steps to prove Young's inequality in general.  However your Question concerns validity of the inequality $||f*g||_{L^\infty} \leq || fg||_{L^1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a point $x$ and define $G(y) = g(x-y)$. Observe that $\|G\|_q = \|g\|_q$. Then $$|f \ast g(x)| \le \int |f(y)g(x-y)| \, dy = \int |f(y) G(y)| \, dy = \|fG\|_1.$$
Now apply Holder's inequality.

Comment: but wouldnt that imply that the $L^\infty$  norm of $f*g$ is smaller than the $L^1$ norm of fg?

Comment: That would contradict what @user296602  said

Comment: $G$ depends on $x$. There is no reason to expect that $\|fg\|_1 = \|fG\|_1$.

Comment: Why is $\|G\|_q = \|g\|_q$? When I try to make a change of variables I end up with an extra negative ...